# GroupBox header template

Tags: wpf, templates, header, styles, foreground

My Groupbox template is defined as so

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type GroupBox}" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="SomeColour" 
                        Background="SomeColour"
                        CornerRadius="4">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" ContentSource="Header" 
                                          Margin="2"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How do I make it so that if the Header is set to a simple simple string, e.g

```
<GroupBox Header="The header!" />
```

The text is bold and with some default colour?

I tried the following, but it only works for the weight, not the colour.

```
<ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" TextBlock.Foreground="Red" 
                  TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

Edit : here is the textblock style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource LabelForegroundBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledLabelForegroundBrush}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Edit 2 : If I place the following in `<Window.Resources>` it seems to work, yet if I place them in `<Application.Resources>`, .. it fails???

```
<XXX.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type GroupBox}" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" ContentSource="Header" TextElement.Foreground="Red" />
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </XXX.Resources>
```

Usage :

```
<GroupBox Header="Header">
        <Button Content="Content" />
    </GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You need attached properties `TextElement.FontWeight` and `TextElement.Foreground` instead.</s>

```
<ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"
                  Margin="2"
                  TextElement.FontWeight="Bold"
                  TextElement.Foreground="Red"/>
```

---

> In case style is under Application resources, it
>   ignores the foreground set on ContentPresenter. If i have it under Window resources, it works
>   fine.

However, you can **override Style for TextBlock and set only `Foreground` property. Also you can inherit all other properties from Style declared under App resources using `BasedOn`**. Place that style under resource of ContentPresenter so that it gets overridden only for your ContentPresenter.

This will work:

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" ContentSource="Header" 
                  Margin="2" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold">
    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="TextBlock"
              BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
           <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
       </Style>
     </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. It seems to still pick up the foreground colour Ive defined for my TextBlock template.

Comment: TextBlock Template? Can you post that as well? AFAIK, TextBlock doesn't have Template property.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Textblock style, I posted it above

Comment: Still that won't be an issue. Can you confirm by removing Setter of Foreground from Style if that's an issue? But i don't think it will have any effect.

Comment: If I remove the foreground setter in the TextBlock, it works, but I don't really want to do that. I guess maybe I shouldn't have an implicit textblock style in my theme at all?

Comment: I am not sure how you doing it because i tried this in small app and it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Please see Edit2. I tried in small application too and noticed that it seems to work only if I place them in Windows.Resources, and not App.Resources. Can I ask where you were placing the styles?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I have updated my answer. Please check. You can override Foreground value without removing it from under App resources and stil gettting properties set in that default style.

Comment: Thankyou. Why is it happening though? Why is it behaving differently when used in Window as opposed to App resources?

Comment: Not pretty sure but my best guess would be that `Resources are resolved by moving up the Visual Tree and gets resolved with first resource found while travelling up the Visual Tree`. But in your code `ContentPresenter i guess is not coming under Visual Tree of window since it's applied as seperate template. However, everything does fall under Application that's why style declared under application resources gets applied on it`. This is my guess though not pretty sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type GroupBox}" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="SomeColour" 
                    Background="SomeColour"
                    CornerRadius="4">
                        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="2"> 
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion but I'm trying to avoid hacks as it will be used in a theme