# WPF : Can we make groupbox header editable at runtime

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

i want groupbox's header editable that means at runtime i want it to be open for edit like we do rename in microsoft excelsheet in bottom left.

i came to know we can do it by control template but don't know how to write template for it.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20825669/2470362)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to create Editable Header:

```
    <GroupBox>
        <GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="Editable Header"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="Some Content" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </GroupBox>
```

Or if you want to modify the template of all control?
Then you can find sample here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms744748(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: here we are using textbox in header it works as textbox, my req is something diff, i want it to be editable on mouse double click like excel sheet tab sheets.

Comment: i don't want final code, i am asking how can we achieve that req with textbox ? is that possible ? because textbox is open for anytime edit.